# Laravel Query a casted field

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using casting on my Model to cast a text field to an array.

```
protected $casts = [
    'humidity' => 'array'
];
```

The following data is in that field in my database

```
["very_dry","dry"]
```

Now I'm trying to query a Model that returns all Models where the humidity field is "dry".
I've tried the following methods

```
Product::where('humidity', 'dry');
Product::whereIn('humidity', ['dry']);
Product::whereIn('humidity', 'dry');
```

None of the above methods is retuning a result for the Model that I have in the database.

Comment: Is it stored using JSON in the DB? Laravel added a query for JSON strings recently: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#json-where-clauses

Comment: no it's a text field, our production databases are still on MySQL 5.6 so the json field isn't an option.

Comment: That's a tricky one. Something like `Product::where('humidity', 'like', '%"dry"%');` is close but I am not certain it would constrain it to just `dry` and not include `very_dry`